# How to analyze and report HTTP responses in JMeter

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

I have a CSV file of values that needs to be run against a REST endpoint with JMeter. I have the project set up roughly like this:

- Thread Group

  - HTTP Request

    - CSV Data Set Config
    - JSR223 PostProcessor
    - XPath Extractor

I use the XPath Extractor to look for a particular path in the HTTP Response. Then I use the JSR233 PostProcessor to evaluate that path output and set a variable with `vars.set` to track what values I get.

This seems like a really hacky way to write something like this. What I need is track counts of results that were "good" versus "bad" and the endpoint unfortunately doesn't use HTTP error codes (not my choice) to specify when something failed (like a 404 when nothing comes back. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) which will additionally allow you to conditionally set pass/fail criteria like:

```
if (1 != 2) {
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
    prev.setResponseCode("404");
}
```

`prev` is the instance of parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see the JavaDoc for all available methods and fields. JMeter provides few more [Assertions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps), maybe you won't even have to go for these JSR223 Elements

In regards to tracking "good" and "bad", when your test finishes you can use i.e. [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener or even build a [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which will contain summary information and some nice charts.